# Tracking indexes in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, indexing, tracking, monitor

I'm looking to keep track of indexes in the DB. I would mostly like to keep track of the names. The only way I know how is to query and insert the result(indexes) in a table. I am just wondering if there are any other ways. How do you guys keep track of your indexes?
Thanks

Comment: That highly depends on the **actual, concrete database system** you're using. SQL is just the query language - that alone doesn't define these kinds of things. Please update your tags with a relevant database product tag - `mysql`, `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server` or whatever else it is you're using!

Comment: What do you mean "keep track" ??  Just a list of index names?  Usage data?  Size?  Please elaborate.

Comment: It would mostly be the names of the index.

Answer (score 1):

You can list table/index names, and some basic usage data with this:

```
USE {DatabaseName}
GO
SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME(sis.OBJECT_ID) TableName, si.name AS IndexName,
sis.user_seeks, sis.user_scans, sis.user_lookups, sis.user_updates
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats sis
INNER JOIN sys.indexes si ON sis.OBJECT_ID = si.OBJECT_ID AND sis.Index_ID = si.Index_ID
--WHERE sis.Database_ID = DB_ID('yourdbnamehere') 
--AND sis.OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('yourtablenamehere');
GO
```

[Link to source.](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/03/sql-server-2008-find-if-index-is-being-used-in-database/)